# C Struct with pointer to the function?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, function-pointers

Can anybody explain what is written in this structure in C

```
struct Structure {
  int i;
  void (*function)(struct Structure*);    
 } ;
```

Comment: What is there to explain?  You recognize that it is a struct with a function-pointer.

Comment: An integer variable and a pointer to a function that takes a pointer to `struct` and returns `void`.

Comment: The `function` member is a pointer to a function that returns nothing and takes a pointer to a `struct Structure` as its argument.  The key item is "pointer to function"; you can search on that.  As for the curious syntax, that's just "the way it is".

Comment: Somebody please create an answer, to get this out of the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a "working example":

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Structure {
    int i;
    void (*function)(struct Structure *);
};

void foo(struct Structure *);
void bar(struct Structure *);

int main(void) {
    struct Structure a = {0, foo};
    struct Structure b = {42, NULL}; // don't call b.function() just yet!!
    a.function(&b);
    b.function(&a);
}

void foo(struct Structure *a) {
    if (a->function == NULL) a->function = bar;
    printf("value from foo: %d\n", a->i);
}

void bar(struct Structure *a) {
    printf("value from bar: %d\n", a->i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @jonathen-leffler has described in comments, the structure has 2 members.
The first member in the structure holds an integer value. The second member is a function pointer, the function takes an input argument of `a pointer to struct Structure' and returns nothing.

so, the 2nd member can point to a function that is declare as below,

```
void someWork(struct Structure* someStruct)
{
  //do some work on struct
  someStruct->i = 5;
}
```

To *declare* and *initialize* a struct of this type, do as below,

```
 struct Structure myStruct;
 myStruct.i=400;
 myStruct.function = &someWork;
```

To make it easier to refer to the function pointer , `typedef` can be used, like so :

```
 typedef void (*func)(struct Structure*);

 //assign it as
 func = &someWork;
```

Comment: can somebody explain in more details this line of code:   void (*function)(struct Structure *); what does this mean (struct Structure *)?